# How to auto-recompile the Linux Kernel with my hardware-specific needs?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, performance

MX Linux 19.2 amd64 - XFCE 4.14

Is there a script or application that detects in-deep all my hardware details, in a manner this auto-configures and recompile the Linux Kernel that works for my current setup only?

This could imply:

- The auto-disabling of a lot of built-in modules which makes the kernel more lightweight in RAM,
- Fewer CPU cycles for operations related to modules that I really need as built-in,
- The auto-configuration of parameters that my slower setup needs because of its legacy,
- and maybe the activation of things I could need and I didn't know, like legacy drivers (?).

All these operations determined from the script/application-preferred kernel and TROUGHT my current kernel permissions or capabilities. (Obviously, it can't be able to detect which webcam I have if my current kernel doesn't have actual recognization).

Answer (score 1):

Parts of the kernel which are not applicable to your hardware configuration and software needs are normally switched off, i.e. they don't consume RAM or CPU resources, aside from MAC (SeLinux/AppArmor/etc) which, if enabled, must be disabled manually to free up processing resources.

It's unlikely that you can make your PC run substantially faster by compiling it according to your own hardware configuration/software needs. Also it's quite a daunting task if you've never done it previously because we are talking about hundreds of terms you've most likely never heard of.

There are no utilities which enable kernel options which correspond to your hardware that I have heard of.

A good guide on how to compile the kernel is here: http://swift.siphos.be/linux_sea/kernelbuilding.html

If you're interested, I can upload my own kernel configuration - it's as lightweight as possible but it only applies to my hardware. Basing off it will be easier than to work it through from scratch.

And even if you manage to compile the kernel successfully, you'll need to create an initrd because most distros rely on it. My kernel (configuration) doesn't because I have static `/dev` entries to be able to boot it.